# jQuery callback after fadeOut not firing

Tags: jquery, hoverintent, easing

I am still very much learning jQuery/javascript so any pointers and improvements are much appreciated.

I want to hide a div within the callback function of an fadeOut event, however this is not working. Is there anything wrong with the way I am writing this.

```
function hide() {
    var box = $(this);
    box.children("div").children().fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).parent().hide("slow", "easeOutBounce");
    });
};
```

I am using the [`Easing`](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and [`HoverIntent`](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jquery plugins.

[Example of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/scFMx/11/)

Comment: Seems to be hiding the div fine. Is the problem that it is not using the correct effect to do it?

Comment: Although it could do with some re-factoring, it seemed to function as you described it in all the browsers I have installed (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE9)

Comment: The reason you weren't getting the animation is that the content of the div was being hidden by the fadeOut. The empty div was therefore in effect hidden and any animation on it was not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback is firing, the problem is that the `<div>` with the links is being hidden, and then you call a `slideUp()`. But the moment the `<div>` is hidden, the containing div has the height as if it were already finished sliding - so you call it to slide up by no amount.

A workaround is to *almost* `fadeOut()` the links, then slideup (since they're not fadedout entirely, they still have a height), then hide them completely.

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/scFMx/13/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's firing

```
box.children("div").children().fadeOut(500, function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().clone());
    $(this).parent().hide();
    console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

First call to log:

```
<div class="hidden" style="display:block; ">…</div>
```

Second call to log:

```
<div class="hidden" style="display:none; ">…</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all "this" by specify IDs.